# Can't send Invoice in Telegram ("Bad Request: can\'t parse prices JSON object")

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send an invoice message in the Telegram bot, but get an error
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse prices JSON object"}
Here is my send invoice def:

```
def sendInvoice(chat_id):

    invoice = {'chat_id': chat_id,
               'title': 'Оплата услуги',
               'description': 'Лайки на фото для инстаграм',
               'payload': 'Payload',
               'provider_token': 'provider_token',
               'start_parameter': 'insta pay',
               'currency': 'UAH',
               'prices': {'label': 'Цена', 'amount': 300000},
               }


    url = URL + 'sendInvoice'
    response = requests.post(url, invoice)
    print(response.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your list of prices to json serializable -
use the json module built it in python

```
json.dumps([
    {
        "label": "My product",
        "amount": 999999
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use telebot library :

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Code :

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
bot.send_invoice()
```

you can see send_invoice params in [github](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/apihelper.py#L1004).